# python3 script fails when run as sudo

Tags: python-3.x, raspberry-pi

When I run the python script below on a raspberry pi using the pi user, it works perfectly.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

from prometheus_client import start_http_server, Summary, Gauge
import random
import time
import subprocess
import json

# Create a metric to track time spent and requests made.
REQUEST_TIME = Summary('request_processing_seconds', 'Time spent processing request')


# use Gauge to record the metrics
labels = ['server_name', 'server_id']
latencyGauge = Gauge('ping_latency', 'Ping Latency in ms', labels)
downloadGauge = Gauge('download_speed', 'Download speed in bytes', labels)
uploadGauge = Gauge('upload_speed', 'Upload speed in bytes', labels)

# launch a subprocess running the speedtest command
# Decorate function with metric.
@REQUEST_TIME.time()
def process_request(id, t):
    comp = subprocess.run(['speedtest', '-s', id, '-f', 'json'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, universal_newlines=True)
#    print(comp)
    output_str = comp.stdout
#    print(output_str)
    res = json.loads(output_str)
    ping = res["ping"]["latency"]
    upload = res["upload"]["bandwidth"]
    download = res["download"]["bandwidth"]
    server_name = res["server"]["name"]
    print("Result for %s (%s): %d, %d, %d" % (id, server_name, ping, download, upload))
    latencyGauge.labels(server_name, id).set(ping)
    uploadGauge.labels(server_name, id).set(upload)
    downloadGauge.labels(server_name, id).set(download)

    time.sleep(t)



if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Start up the server to expose the metrics.
    start_http_server(8000)
    # Generate some requests.
    while True:
        process_request("1686", 120)
```

However, if I run it with sudo it fails with the following error.

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/speedtest $ sudo ./speedtest.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./speedtest.py", line 46, in <module>
    process_request("1686", 120)
  File "<decorator-gen-1>", line 2, in process_request
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/prometheus_client/context_managers.py", line 66, in wrapped
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "./speedtest.py", line 27, in process_request
    res = json.loads(output_str)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/json/__init__.py", line 348, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/json/decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/json/decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

The reason for running the script in sudo is that I want it to start up automatically by editing the /etc/rc.local

What could be the cause?

Answer (score 0):

Resolved.

This root cause of the problem was that upon the very first use of the speedtest software, the user is required to accept by typing YES (or decline) twice before being able to proceed.

Since the script was expecting a JSON reply, the text presented upon the initial run was breaking the JSON parsing.

Hence the resolution is to run the speedtest without any options (default) at least once using sudo as shown below.

[image]